# Ubuntu Browser Autoscroll on Middle Mouse click?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Does anyone know an alternative ?
I want the same smooth Autoscroll functionality you have on Windows but not as Chrome Extension, they dont work well.
Example try visiting this page : https://www.tennon.io/
I already tried Scroll Extensions like [this](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan?hl=en-US).
I'm a Web Developer and even programmed my little own [Autoscroll Extension](https://github.com/onurz24/AutoScroll_Extension/blob/main/Extension/assets/ts/background.ts).
I also don't want to use Firefox and activate this in the settings.

(Kubuntu: 23.10 x86_64, Kernel: 6.5.0-13-generic)